# Adding an image to android's phone top bar

Tags: android

I want to add an image- once my app is installed on the android to the top bar (where the battary information is, the whatsup icon and so on...)- I'm sorry I couldnt fint it's technical name

Do you know how could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

[`Notifications`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) are used for that.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html). See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to learn more about notification.